# Value of $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ for $x=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Why the value of $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ for $x=0$, is 1 and not 0?

Comment: Because the constant term, corresponding to $n=0$ is $\frac {x^0}{0!}=1$.

Comment: Do you mean corresponding to x=0?

Comment: If you are allowed to assume that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!},$ then the result follows since $e^0=1.$

Comment: Then why does $\frac{0^0}{0!}=1$? And shouldn't diverge the series in this case?

Comment: Although $0^0$ is an undetermined form, in the context of power series we always define $x^0 = 1$.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One way to keep it sorted out is to use the domain $x\in(0,\infty]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's intuitive that the sum of no numbers is defined as zero. Less intuitive is that the product of no numbers is defined as one.

Symbolically:

$$\sum_{\text{false}} x = 0$$

$$\prod_{\text{false}} x = 1$$

No matter what number $x$ is, even zero.

One reason $0^0 = 1$ by definition is because the cardinality (how many elements there are in a set, denoted $\vert \cdot \vert$) of the number of functions from a set $X$ to a set $Y$, denoted $Y^X$, is given by:

$$\left\vert Y^X \right\vert = |Y|^{|X|}$$

and there is one and only one function from the empty set to itself:

$$1 = \left\vert \varnothing^\varnothing \right\vert = |\varnothing|^{|\varnothing|} = 0^0$$

See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_Power_of_Zero for more reasons.

Edit: In the context of taking limits, we refer to $0^0$ as an indeterminate form because you *cannot* conclude $x^y \to 1$ just because $x \to 0$ and $y \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Because when dealing with power series it is assumed that $0^0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have by convention $$\left.\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|_{x=0}=\left.\frac{x^0}{0!}\right|_{x=0}+0+0+0+\dots=1+0+0+\dots=1.$$